# Ext.Net 100% Width Layout

Tags: c#, extjs, asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

I started some days ago with Ext.NET (on MVC4 site) and I created some Forms with Ext.NET but I can't set 100% width to containers.

Someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the Width of an  will fill 100% of the width of its parent Container.

If the parent Container is an Ext.NET Container type (such as Panel, Window, etc), you might also try setting .Layout="fit" on the parent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Layout="fit" dosent works all the time there no responsive component there you can also take the ScreenWidth using c# code and update give the parameters of width and height on page load so your page will be fit everywhere.